# How to get a list of all non-bot members, rewriting Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a bot that scales a number, based on the number of members in the guild. However, I don't want to include bots.

**My Code:**

```
members = []
for member in client.get_all_members():
    if str(member.type) != 'bot':
        members.append(member)
print(members)
number = 10 * len(members)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres already a feature in discord api library.

[`client.users`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.users)

Returns a list of all the users the bot can see.

Simply use

```
len(client.users)
```

**Note that a member may be bot, but user is never a bot.**

Comment: Just tested this really quickly, it seems `client.users` *does* include bots, and the `User` object also happens to have a `bot` property.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension to make a list of all users where `member.bot` is `False`.

```
members = [member for member in client.get_all_members() if not member.bot]
print(len(members))
```

This takes the `client.get_all_members()` generator and makes a new list in one line where all the users are not bots.

Then, we just print the length of that list, which you can use as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem,  I was using the wrong format, all member objects have a boolean value called bot i just had to query it for false

```
        members = []
        for member in client.get_all_members():
            if member.bot == False:
                members.append(member)
        print(members)
        number = 10 * len(members)
```

Comment: You can also use `if not member.bot` rather than `if member.bot == False`.